# Is there a way to check if a function is missing keyword await in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, async-await, eslint

So I am using async/await in my nodejs code, and I have to use it. There is no change in that, but since I have so many files, sometimes I miss adding await when calling the async function. I tried googling to find if there is an extension to check the missing await or if there is a npm properties to check that. I cant find anyone. I found this online:

Disallow async functions which have no await expression (require-await)
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await

It says require-await might help, but I am not sure how to install require-await. I tried "npm install require-await", that did not work since it says its not a valid command.

or Is there any other way to check that?

Comment: What isn't a valid command? And you'd still likely need to enable it, both in the rules and any plugins.

Comment: So i tried to install like this and got this error:                        
 C:\Development\qa-node-tests>npm install require-await
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/require-await - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'require-await@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: --- Do you how to install?

Comment: ... It's part of eslint already.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work, so I was trying to see if there is some other way to fix that

Comment: did anybody ever figure this out?

Comment: apparently, there is not a way to do that or at least I haven't found it yet